# Alert user if there is a duplicate value in array

Tags: javascript

I have a recursive array structure like below:

```
var trees = [{
    name: "Node-1",
    myObj : { name : "Node-1"},
    nodes: 
    [
           {   name: "Node-1-1", myObj : { name : "Node-1"}, nodes[]}
    ]
  },{
    name: "Node2",
    myObj : { name : "Abc"},
    nodes: []
  }];

var obj = {
    name: "Node-1-1",
    myObj : { name : "Node-1"},
    nodes: []
  }
```

Now I want to match obj.myObj.name value in trees array and if found then it should return true or false immediately and stop further traversing through the tree and alert the user regarding duplicate found.

Now as you can `obj.myObj.name` value is matching with first record so I want to alert user but I am always getting false.

Here `obj.myObj.name` value i.e Node-1 is matching with first record of `trees[0].myObj.name` so I want to alert user.

**Update :**

Based on answer given on this question i have change the code and sample input but now when I have Pqr in `trees[0].myObj.name` and obj contains pqr so while searching obj value in trees I want to skip pqr value from trees as because pqr doesn't exist in other trees record still I am getting pqr exist.

```js
var trees = [{
    name: "Node-1",
    myObj : { name : "Pqr"},
    nodes: 
 [
           {   name: "Node-1-1", myObj : { name : "Abc"}, nodes:[]}
 ]
  },{
    name: "Node2",
    myObj : { name : "Abc"},
    nodes: []
  }];

var obj = {
    name: "Node-1-1",
    myObj : { name : "Pqr"},
    nodes: []
  }
  
  checkDuplicateNodeName();
  
  function checkDuplicateNodeName() {
        var name = obj.myObj.name;
        var dupe = false;
        for(var idx = 0; idx < trees.length; idx++) {
            if(trees[idx].myObj.name != name)
                continue;
            if(isDuplicateName(trees[idx], name))
            {
                dupe = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(dupe){
            alert('The name "' + name + ' already exists');
        }
        else
            alert('All is well');
    }

function isDuplicateName(node, name) {
        var dupeName = node.myObj.name && name && node.myObj.name.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase();
        if(dupeName) return true;
    
        if(node.nodes){
            for(var idx=0; idx< node.nodes.length; idx++) {
                if(isDuplicateName(node.nodes[idx], name)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: i really do not understand which name is important, the name of the outer object of a node or myObj.name? btw. the data structure is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will provide you the solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
   var trees = [{
    name: "Node-1",
    myObj : { name : "Node-1"},
    nodes: 
    [
           {   name: "Node-1-1", myObj : { name : "Node-1"}, nodes:[]}
    ]
  },{
    name: "Node2",
    myObj : { name : "Abc"},
    nodes: []
  }];

var obj = {
    name: "Node-1-1",
    myObj : { name : "Node-1"},
    nodes: []
  }
  
  for(var i = 0; i<trees.length; i++){
 if(obj.myObj.name == trees[i].myObj.name){
  alert("duplicate found");
  break;
 }
 for(var j=0; j<trees[i].nodes.length; j++){
  if(obj.myObj.name == trees[j].nodes[j].myObj.name){
  alert("duplicate found");
  break;
  }
 }
 break;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="data">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please try my current sample inputs and also see my update

Comment: What exactly you would like to do. do you want to run your code after duplicate alert or stop execution.

Comment: Now i shouldnt get alert with my current input as you can see i dont have pqr value twice so it should work fine now.Can you use my input and see what you are getting?